# Getting the names of the second level of a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame` in the form:

```
df
                0         1         2         3
Open  1  1.046031 -1.653869  1.039417  0.029429
      2  0.149056 -1.572694  0.562478 -0.974489
Close 1 -0.475074 -0.052126 -2.124979 -1.918538
      1  0.862663  0.405697  0.455616 -0.542472
```

I can get the first level data using some like:

```
df2 = df.xs('Open', level=0, drop_level=False)

               0         1         2         3
Open 1  1.046031 -1.653869  1.039417  0.029429
     2  0.149056 -1.572694  0.562478 -0.974489
```

for example. Is there a way to get the names of the second level (i.e `1`, `2` etc) from the above cropped dataframe (`df2`) or should I know them before hand to call something like:

```
df2.loc[idx['Open', '1'], :]
```

To make it clear, I know the level 0 names (`'Open'`, `'Close'`) but ignore the second level. Is there a way to get them so as to use them in the above syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) first and then get values of level:

```
print (df2.index.remove_unused_levels().levels[1])
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Or:

```
print (df2.index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values(1))
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Better see difference if select second `Close` level:

```
df22 = df.xs('Close', level=0, drop_level=False)
print (df22)
                0         1         2         3
Close 1 -0.475074 -0.052126 -2.124979 -1.918538
      1  0.862663  0.405697  0.455616 -0.542472

#get default index values - not what need
print (list(df22.index.levels[1]))
[1, 2]

#get unique values without all levels
print (df22.index.remove_unused_levels().levels[1])
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')

#get values if index
print (df22.index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values(1))
Int64Index([1, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply index function to your dataframe. It gives you levels and labels. If you want to get level 2 names:

```
list(df.index.levels[1])

['1', '2']
```